# MkMapView Zoom Level

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I m using MkMapView with google maps.I succeed to show map view and address with annotation pin.But I want increased zoom level.How Can I Set it programmatically????

```
-(void)showMyAddress
{

//Hide the keypad
MKCoordinateRegion region;
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta=0.2;
span.longitudeDelta=0.2;

CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [self addressLocation];
region.span=span;
region.center=location;



if(addAnnotation != nil) {
    [mapView removeAnnotation:addAnnotation];
    [addAnnotation release];
    addAnnotation = nil;
}


addAnnotation = [[AddAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location ];
[addAnnotation setMTitle:@"abc"];
[addAnnotation setMSubTitle:@"def."]




[mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];

[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
[mapView regionThatFits:region];


}


-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) addressLocation {
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 
                       [@"abc" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy  error:nil];
NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

double latitude = 0.0;
double longitude = 0.0;

if([listItems count] >= 4 && [[listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
    latitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
    longitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
}
else {

}
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = latitude;
location.longitude = longitude;

return location;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make the span.longitudeDelta and span.latitudeDelta smaller (i.e. set it to 0.02 instead of 0.2 to have a 10X zoom).